# What are some good chess calendars?

Tags: tournament

I am having a hard time keeping up with recent tournaments. Are there any good online calendars?

Comment: Depending on quite what you mean by "keeping up", you may find the app *Follow Chess* helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to the fide calendar: https://www.fide.com/calendar

Also, this link includes the tournaments which will feature some of the top super GMs (e.g., the Olympiad, Sinquefield Cup, Altibox Norway Chess): https://chess24.com/en/read/news/2020-chess-calendar